# Can TEB or Other Local Planners Work Without move_base?

Tags: navigation, move-base, path-planning, planner, teb-local-planner

I am working on path planning and path tracking for a while and I wonder, can TEB local planner (or any other local planner on ROS, DWA lets say) function without *move_base*?

I mean do I have to use *move_base/nav_stack* if I want to develop a good and complex local planner like TEB? If not, why everyone integrates their planners as plug-ins to *move_base*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People integrate into `move_base` for software engineering reasons: `move_base` provides a convenient common interface and integration with local/global planning, goal management, failure recovery, and command velocity calculations. You certainly could write your own code to wrap your planner in the same way as `move_base`, but why would you when there is already a widely used and supported system for it?

I think you may be partly assuming that a planner is capable of moving the robot. It isn't: a planner (such as TEB) simply plans. You then need to interpret that path as a series of commands to be sent to the robot. `move_base` handles this (in addition to the other nice-to-have features like failure recovery).

Comment: Just a note here - TEB is a typically used as a local planner (ROS 2 properly calls this a "controller") - it converts the global plan (made elsewhere) into those controls. The rest of this answer is correct though, move_base gives you access to that global planner, costmaps, etc.